# django set multiple allowed hosts

Tags: django, heroku

I'm trying to set multiple allowed hosts in django

I have setting configured in production settings `production.py` as

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = env('DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS')
```

which I can then set on heroku with:

```
heroku config:set 'DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS' = 'www.example.com'
```

However how can I add multiple hosts via this method?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can provide a delimiter then split the string in django

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = env('DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS').split(',')
heroku config:set 'DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS' = 'www.example.com,foo.com'
```

Answer (score 6):

To define multiple values for allowed hosts in `settings.py` file use like:

> ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['000.08.10.11','111.22.33.44','www.abcdefgh.com']